# FCK Editor + Update Panel + ValidateRequest="false"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, fckeditor, serverside-javascript

When I set fckEditor to Some Value like

```
fckDescription.Value = "Description Text";
```

It creates problems such as Update Panel not doing Async PostBack for DropDownList control and gives error when DropDownList selection changes:

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500`

But when I **Comment** out these lines

```
// fckDescription.Value = "Description Text";
```

**It Works Fine... I am wondering why it is so !!?!!**

Also, fckEditor is outside UpdatePanel and DropDownList Control is inside UpdatePanel.

Comment: @All http://forums.asp.net/p/1095266/1651601.aspx as per this link setting `ValidateRequest="false"` solves my problem for now but this is not good solution, I think so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterOnSubmitStatement(EditorID.GetType(), "editor", "FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance('" + EditorID.ClientID + "').UpdateLinkedField();");
```

Comment: It Worked when i added it to my Page_Load Event